# Is there a significant impact of the new standard's features on the boost library implementation in C++11?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-spirit, boost-variant

Is there a significant impact of the new standard's features on the **boost** library implementation in **C++11**?

Especially interested in `boost::variant` (BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES) and `boost::spirit` parts of the library in light of the presence of *variadic templates*.

Is there a good article about this?

Comment: the only impact is some things can be removed from boost (for example shared_ptr), and the implementation

Comment: @BЈовић I don't think that's accurate, boost::shared_ptr still has more features, boost::regex many more and a different interface to boot; Also, the integration with PhoenixV2 is present for boost shared_ptr, but not std::[tr1::]shared_ptr and so on.

Comment: @BЈовић that's not true. With C++11, many parts of the libraries *could* indeed be implemented easier, but probably won't be necessarily to be backwards compatible with C++03 compilers. On the other hand, some parts will need to be improved, e.g. to support move-only types. That will be interesting especially for variant - a variant that contains move-only types should be movable in C++11. I know of a ticket for Boost.Optional to become move-aware, so it seems they are at it :)

Comment: @Dukales Boost is specifically designed to be C++03 friendly, so most libraries don't use the 'goodness' of C++11 by default. However, as an example, Fusion will use variadics when you include `fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp` - and you'd actually see compile times reduce when you switch from boost::tuple (however, see above: boost tuples have (far) more features, and a different interface so don't assume it's a drop in replacement)

Comment: @ArneMertz Good points. I forgot about the move

Comment: @sehe I'm ask about the implementation.

Comment: @Dukales I know (I addressed that: "Boost is specifically designed to be C++03 friendly, so most libraries don't use the 'goodness' of C++11 by default", also the Fusion example). By now, see my answer as well - HTH

Comment: Some classes can now be way cleaner then before. For example, `boost::mpl::vector` is now clean if needed thanks to variadic templates (nothing to do with the previous implementations that used macros in order to be usable with too much boilerplate). Moreover, variadic templates improve a lot the time needed to compile this class (see [this blog post](http://cpptruths.blogspot.fr/2010/03/faster-meta-programs-using-gcc-45-and.html)).

Comment: I retracted my very own 'mark as duplicate'. To my own surprise it turns out that the specific wording of the question made it sollicit quite a bunch of information that isn't covered elsewhere <blush/> Sorry :)

Comment: @ArneMertz: I see no reason why a C++03 and a C++11 implementation could not live side-by-side. This would ensure both backward compatibility for C++03 and better compile times (and less limitations) for C++11. Boost.Config is all about detecting compiler features (and working around bugs), so new macros like `BOOST_COMPILER_SUPPORT_VARIADIC_TEMPLATE` or the like could pop up and be used to simplify implementation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think that exists, look at BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES in the example I mentioned before: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/fusion/adapted.hpp

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, such macros already live in Boost.Config.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that's a bit of what I meant by "won't be necessarily", in the sense of that the C++03 implementations need to remain anyways and C++11 implementations will be provided only where they provide a benefit, at least for the time being. Right now, move-awareness will be of more importance than to provide variadic template implementations for features that still work well with BOOST_PP_* n-ary function overload abominations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I was writing my third comment, which is going to address the topic of Spirit specifically. I decided to mesh my comments into an answer anyways)

Boost Spirit is going to be using C++11 features exclusively (i.e. drop C++03 support) so that it can take full advantage of the improved TMP abilities and reduced compile times - compilation times are a big drawback of using Spirit V2.

**Spirit X3** (the experimental V3 branch) is already under active development:

> And in yet other news: Spirit V3 will be C++11 only and move-enabled:
>
> [Feb 11, 2013; 12:02pm](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Error-with-container-within-sequence-tc4642517.html#a4642614), Joel de Guzman wrote:
>
> > No, X3 will be C++11 only. Pure. No workarounds.
> >
> > Keep in mind though that X3 is, by its nature, X-perimental. A lot of things can happen from X3 to final. I am not closing the door on C++03 support, although I am heavily inclined to move on without 03. V2 will not be going away anytime soon anyway.

Also, expression templates will be `auto`-safe, no more need for the BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO macro whenever you want to keep a 'raw' parser expression bound to a local variable.>

---

I found the link to the Spirit X3 repositories:

- https://github.com/djowel/spirit_x3 (github)

Note the status of the development at http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/02/23/spirit-x3-on-github/

Comment: `Spirit V3 will be C++11 only and move-enabled` sounds good. This should lead to a reduction in compile time?

Comment: Added a link to Spirit X3 repository

Comment: @Dukales yes, this vastly reduces compile times (e.g. - browsing SpiritX3: TOTAL :   4.27 secs vs. Spirit2:  TOTAL :  10.00 secs)

Comment: I think more libraries should take this 'bold' approach, using C++11 features leads to less code, easier to read and smaller compilation times.

Comment: @demorge I agree, but I also appreciate that Boost needs to keep a large user base. I a sense, Spirit is an outlier, in that it's highly specific (contrast, e.g. with MPL) and already is so heavy on the compiler, that it basically requires a very recent compiler anyways. These two factors make it so that Spirit wouldn't alienate _much_ of it's user base by making this move. Also, like Spirit Classic, the current SpiritV2 will continue to exist for compatibility purposes.

Comment: When they say "C++11 only", do they mean to support Visual Studio at all, or are they going to use any feature where applicable, no matter where it is or is not supported?

Comment: @NicolBolas I have no authoritative source, but I can only assume MSVC support is a given. I have always presumed this is a requirement for each and any boost library project.

Comment: @sehe [Boost Library Requirements and Guidelines](http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Portability): "There is no requirement that a library run on C++ compilers which do not conform to the ISO standard.", etc